# How can I use packer to dynamically change a template?

Tags: unreal-engine4, steam, packer

So I've been fighting for a good time with Packer and HCL and I'm struggling to solve something which seems quite trivial. I'm using Packer to build an Unreal Engine game server image, to support having multiple instances of the UE server I'm leveraging onto supervisord to do the job. So far so good until we had to integrate Steam and that's where my problems started.

Before steam I had this code:

```
[program:mygame]
command=/opt/game_server/Game.sh
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)s
numprocs=number_of_processes
stopasgroup=true
user=ubuntu
stdout_logfile=/opt/game_server/logs/supervisor/ueserver/%(program_name)s_%(process_num)s_stdout.log
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=1MB
stdout_logfile_backups=10
stderr_logfile=/opt/game_server/logs/supervisor/ueserver/%(program_name)s_%(process_num)s_stderr.log
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=1MB
stderr_logfile_backups=10
```

So all I did is inline modification of the string `number_of_processes` based on how big my server needs to be.

The problem with Steam is that it needs an argument with the query port, something like this:

```
command=/opt/game_server/Game.sh -queryport=27015
```

If you don't set that up you can only run one instance per box which is not quite efficient, I'm trying to find a way to dynamically set that port so I can get the benefit of setting up the amounts of servers I want and avoid something like this:

```
[program:dominionserver-1]
command=/opt/game_server/DominionServer.sh -queryport=27015
stopasgroup=true
user=ubuntu
stdout_logfile=/opt/game_server/logs/supervisor/ueserver/%(program_name)s_stdout.log
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=1MB
stdout_logfile_backups=10
stderr_logfile=/opt/game_server/logs/supervisor/ueserver/%(program_name)s_stderr.log
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=1MB
stderr_logfile_backups=10

[program:dominionserver-2]
command=/opt/game_server/DominionServer.sh -queryport=27016
stopasgroup=true
user=ubuntu
stdout_logfile=/opt/game_server/logs/supervisor/ueserver/%(program_name)s_stdout.log
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=1MB
stdout_logfile_backups=10
stderr_logfile=/opt/game_server/logs/supervisor/ueserver/%(program_name)s_stderr.log
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=1MB
stderr_logfile_backups=10
[...]
```

I think I can use this functionality of Packer: https://www.packer.io/docs/templates/hcl_templates/functions/file/templatefile but I can't work out how can I modify a particular bit of a file.

Comment: What is the range of ports you want to use, or at least the logic behind the range of ports? Where on the server's filesystem should this config file be located?

Comment: Range of ports could be between 27015 to 27115, I don't think it'll be more than that. The supervisord config files will be in the etc volume if that's what you meant.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up leveraging on Ansible to achieve what I want, so in Packer I have this:

```
  provisioner "ansible" {
    playbook_file = "./ansible/playbook.yaml"
    extra_arguments = [
      "--extra-vars", "server_count=${var.number_of_processes}"
    ]
  }
```

Where the playbook is:

```
---
- name: Deploy dynamic supervisor
  hosts: 'all'
  vars:
    query_port: 27014
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo
  tasks:
    - name: copy supervisor
      template:
        src: templates/gameserver.j2
        dest: "/home/ubuntu/gameserver{{ item }}.conf"
      with_sequence: start=1 end={{ server_count }}
```

and the relevant j2 template:

```
[program:gameserver-{{ item }}]
command=/opt/game_server/GameServer.sh -queryport={{ query_port|int + item|int }}
stopasgroup=true 
user=ubuntu
```